# Why email should always be verified in US-EAST-1 Region in AWS SES?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email using AWS SES with Django and I am getting the following error:

```
MessageRejected: An error occurred (MessageRejected) when calling the SendRawEmail operation: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region **US-EAST-1**: my-email@gmail.com
```

The above error is not coming only if I verify emails in the **US-EAST-1** region. But I am using configurations like this:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django_amazon_ses.EmailBackend"
AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
AWS_SES_REGION = 'ap-south-1'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
```

As per my configurations if I verify my emails in **ap-south-1** region then It should work.

Please make me understand. I am new to AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SES won't allow you to send email from emails you have not proved you own (verification process) -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html

If you are trying to perform some test you can verify your personal email account via SES console.